# java.security.Principal mapping with AD

Tags: java, active-directory, kerberos, waffle

I need some help in understanding a basic concept. 
The `HttpServletRequest` provides a method called `getUserPrincipal()` that returns a `java.security.Principal` object.  Using this object we can get the user information from the AD using kerberos authentication via waffle implementation.

My question is which attribute of AD does it fetch?  As per my tests, it looks like the `samAccountName`, Or is it `userPrincipalName`?

Could someone please help me resolve this confusion?

Comment: i would appreciate if you can provide the explanation for downvote. I don't see any reason for that as the question is quite valid. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

so looks like i was able to clarify my confusion. the getUserPrincipal() returns the samAccountName from the AD.